# Add DOM objects to an array in a certain order, based on data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a custom slider, with the possibility for the end user, to prioritize which slides should come first, I figured the best way to do this was making a data-priority on each of the main DOM elements, that to start with are set to Opacity: 0, the maximum of DOM elements in this case is 3.

However as you can see in the code, it will simply grab the DOM elements from the top and down, and ignore the data- value.

How do I put these in the correct order into the array?

```
    var hideSlide = 0;
    var showSlide = 1;
    var amountOfSlides = 2;
    var slideArray = [];
    var dataPriority = 1;

    $('.hero-detail-container').each(function(e) {
        if ( $(this).data('active') == '1' && $(this).data('priority') == '1' ) {
        slideArray.push($(this));
    }
    else if ( $(this).data('active') == '1' && $(this).data('priority') == '2' ) {
        slideArray.push($(this));
    }
    if ( $(this).data('active') == '1' && $(this).data('priority') == '3' ) {
        slideArray.push($(this));
    }

        // THE ISSUE IS HERE
        // The code will push to slideArray in the order
        // it sees the DOM elements from the top, even if
        // the priority says the first element is number 2 fx.

    });

    slideArray[0].css({
        "opacity": "1"
    });

    setInterval(function() {

        console.log(slideArray);

        slideArray[hideSlide].css({
            "opacity": "0"
        });
        slideArray[showSlide].css({
            "opacity": "1"
        });

        if ( showSlide >= amountOfSlides ) {
            hideSlide = amountOfSlides;
            showSlide = 0;
        }
        else if ( hideSlide == 2 && showSlide == 0 ) {
            hideSlide = 0;
            showSlide = 1;
        }
        else {
            hideSlide++;
            showSlide++;
        }

    }, slideTimer());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of methods to do this.

  1: Have multiple arrays you push data too and then combine them at the end.

  2: Loop through the data-set multiple times to push in the order you want. Use JQuery to get the elements you want.

3: Sort the array after you've added the elements.

```
slideArray.sort(function(a,b){ return a.data('priority') - b.data('priority') });
```

Comment: I just tried the 3rd option, it worked right away, thank you!